# Spring Social XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

My application uses Spring XML configuration. I must add Spring Social's functionality(i want to configure it also by XML) but i encounter an error:

nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.social.connect.signin.web.ProviderSignInController

I have tried configuring by XML in my application and also in the spring-social-showcase sample app but the same error... All the jars are in the right place... I took the configuration model from the Spring Social guide. Did anyone configured it by XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the probelm... It seems that there are 2 ProviderSignInController classes in different packages. In the docs there is org.springframework.social.connect.signin.web.ProviderSignInController
and in the jar there is org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController

Comment: There is only one ProviderSignInController. The documentation is simply lacking. They probably moved it after writing the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The `ClassNotFoundException` tells you that your *don't* have all the jars in the right place. You're probably missing `spring-social-web-1.x.x.RELEASE.jar`.